# Distributing amounts of different objects to distinct people

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following exercise and I am wondering if the subsequent solution of mine is correct.

> Alan, Peter, Steve, and Donald have a total of 11 chocolate bars that
>   they are going to divide among themselves. They have 9 Snickers (S), 1
>   Mars (M) and 1 Bounty (B). In how many different ways can they
>   distribute the chocolates among themselves such that each person gets
>   at least one chocolate?

Each person shall have at least one chocolate each, i.e. a total of 4 chocolates. Call these **compulsory**. There are 4 different ways to choose compulsory chocolates:

1. $\{S, S, S, S\}$
2. $\{S, S, S, M\}$
3. $\{S, S, S, B\}$
4. $\{S, S, M, B\}$

Case 1: There is only one way to distribute the four compulsory Snickers among the boys. Then there are $\binom{4}{1}$ ways of distributing the Mars and $\binom{4}{1}$ ways of distributing the Bounty. The remaing five Snickers can be distributed in $\binom{4+5-1}{5}$ ways using the equation $a+b+c+d = 5$. In total: $\binom{4}{1}$$\binom{4}{1}$$\binom{4+5-1}{5}$.

Case 2: There are $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to distribute the one compulsory Mars and one way to distribute the three compulsory Snickers. Then there are $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to distribute the non compulsory Bounty and $\binom{4+6-1}{6}$ ways to distribute the six non compulsory Snickers. In total: $\binom{4}{1}$$\binom{4}{1}$$\binom{4+6-1}{6}$.

Case 3: There are $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to distribute the one compulsory Bounty, $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to distribute the one non compulsory Mars and $\binom{4+6-1}{6}$ ways of distributing the six remaining Snickers. In total: $\binom{4}{1}$$\binom{4}{1}$$\binom{4+6-1}{1}$.

Case 4: There are $\binom{4}{1}$ ways of distributing the one compulsory Mars, then $\binom{3}{1}$ ways of distributing the compulsory Bounty, and one way of distributing the two compulsory Snickers. The remaining seven non compulsory Snickers can be distributed in $\binom{4+7-1}{7}$ different ways. In total: $\binom{4}{1}$$\binom{3}{1}$$\binom{4+7-1}{7}$.

All in all: $\binom{4}{1}$$\binom{4}{1}$$\binom{4+5-1}{5}$ + $\binom{4}{1}$$\binom{4}{1}$$\binom{4+6-1}{6}$ + $\binom{4}{1}$$\binom{4}{1}$$\binom{4+6-1}{1}$ + $\binom{4}{1}$$\binom{3}{1}$$\binom{4+7-1}{7}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to get something like $3824$, which looks far too many: my answer is about half that.

So looking at possible issues with your answer:

- In case 3 you seem to have changed a 6 into a 1, so case 3 does not give the same answer as case 2; I am unclear about whether this is deliberate or not
- I think you may have double, triple or quadruple counted cases like $(SSSS, SSM, SB, SS)$
- To avoid double counting, you might consider cases where the compulsory Mars or Bounty are not accompanied by any Snickers.  You would need to add $\{S,S,S,MB\}$ to your patterns and do the calculations where non-compulsory bars can only be given to people who already have a compulsory Snickers.

Comment: Thank you. Changing 6 to 1 in case 1 was an accident.

Comment: I have been rethinking my solution. Let A, B, C and D be the four boys. There are two cases. **Case 1**: Suppose A has the one Mars and B has the one Bounty. Distribution of the 9 Snickers is a solution to the equation $a + b + (c + 1) + (d + 1) = 9 \iff a + b + c + d = 7$. Thus there are $\binom{4+7-1}{7}$ ways of distributing the chocolates. And there are $2\binom{4}{2} = 4*3$ ways of choosing who is to be A and B. **Case 2**: A has the Bounty and the Mars. There are 4 ways to pick who's gonna be A. The 9 Snickers can be distributed in $\binom{4+7-1}{7}$ ways.

Comment: In total: $2\binom{4}{2}\binom{4+7-1}{7}+4\binom{4+7-1}{7}$.

Comment: @tychicus: That works but I think your second term should use $6$ rather than $7$ as three of the nine are already spoken for so $2\binom{4}{2}\binom{4+7-1}{7}+4\binom{4+6-1}{6}$ is the result I get.

Comment: I agree. I was too quick in the turns. Thanks for the help.